# Auditoria afirma que falhei

Tags: debate, novo-recurso, auditoria

Veja essa imagem:
[image: resultado de uma auditoria]

Respectiva auditoria https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/300494

No caso eu pressionei o botão de edição pois minha intenção era remover da resposta os trechos grifados e talvez trocar o nome do `vetSelvagem` e antes de testar o funcionamento do código. O sistema me acusou de não estar prestando a devida atenção.

Minhas perguntas são:

- Eu errei ao tentar editar e testar funcionamento do código da resposta e deveria ter sinalizado de imediato? **Se errei meu questionamento se encerra aqui**.
- Caso eu não tenha errado, a auditoria não seria mais producente se passasse considerar a ação de editar uma pergunta ou resposta ruim por parte do analista como uma ação válida de análise?
- Se sim, a edição devesse ser auditada como uma ação válida de análise, pode ser modificado o comportamento da ferramenta?

Comment: Eu acho que essa aqui é duplicata, convém procurarmos. Os limites da auditoria já meio que foram discutidos antes EDIT: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=auditoria+is%3Aquestion

Comment: Vale lembrar que a auditoria não é 100% e ela se baseia muito em conteúdos nossos, logo ela pode sim falhar, não estou afirmando que é ou não o caso.

Comment: Sobre a "subpergunta" do que fazer no caso especifico, a sugestão é: "passe fogo de imediato" para estancar o problema, depois edite - eu sempre abro em aba separada pra entender o contexto, a fila é meio esquisita e muitas vezes esconde dados importantes. A intenção original provavelmente era de se focar no problema imediato, mas dá tanto "backfire" que não compensa. Não falo só da auditoria, falo do risco de equívoco no julgamento mesmo.

Comment: Eu também já falhei por algo similar. Às vezes o usuário posta a pergunta com o HTML sendo interpretado já que não está em formato de `código`, e eu queria ver se era esse o problema. Depois disso passei a clicar pra ver os votos quando está suspeito antes de fazer qualquer coisa, porque aí ele me diz que o post já foi excluído (se é uma auditoria) :)

Comment: @Bacco, obrigado a noite vou ler com calma a duplicada e ver o resultado da pesquisa sugerida. Se alguém tiver outras sugestões de leitura ficarei grato.